# Multiply value if it includes a period

Tags: vector, conditional

I download data from an online source, now I have a problem: the source code doesn't allow to differ between values of 10 (which actually stands for 10) and 10.000 (which is 10'000, but *Mathematica* reads it as 10 as well).

Now I'm thinkg about letting all values that include a period like `10.000` multiply with the factor 1000 and let all the values without a period remain the same.

Lets say I have the following vector `a={10.350,20,20.000,10.700,30,40.522}`.

What I want to do is to multiply all elements of `a` except the second (`20`) and fifth one (`30`).

Is there a chance to distinguish between 20 and 20.000 ?

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deselect the integers.

```
a = {10.350, 20, 20.000, 10.700, 30, 40.522};

IntegerQ /@ a
```

> {False, True, False, False, True, False}

To multiply all elements of `a` except 2nd and 5th :-

```
b = DeleteCases[a, _?IntegerQ]
```

> {10.35, 20., 10.7, 40.522}

Times @@ b

> 89752.2

Comment: Thanks very much, I think this should work just fine for my cause:)

Answer (score 3):

It is almost always better to deal with these problems during import rather than afterward.  Follow up Pickett's comment you could use something like this:

```
string = "10.350,20,20.000,10.700,30,40.522";

ImportString[string, "CSV", NumberPoint -> ","]
```

> ```
> {{10350, 20, 20000, 10700, 30, 40522}}
> ```

Except that in your application you would presumably use [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html) with a file path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it'd have been easier doing this while importing the numbers, however I had to extract the numbers from an imported HTML code, therefore I had to sort of scan the text for recurring patterns. I don't think it's possible to handle this before importing then.

Comment: @Phily `ImportString` is still a good approach vs doing your own parsing.